# Blank desktop after login

Tags: unity

Today my 14.04 updated itself not requiring a reboot. After a while I rebooted because of other reasons and then I was pleasantly surprised by a blank screen.

I have tried everything I could think about including

- Reinstalled compiz, unity, ubuntu-desktop, xorg
- Reinstalled and then    removed the nvidia driver

So far nothing has worked. Except for one little thing: my cairo-dock is showing. And that's all.

I tried with [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but none of the answers there helped me. I also tried removing my ~/.Xauthority file and it still doesn't work.

Does anybody know what else I could try?

**UPDATE:**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

When I run that code and then login again the icons on the desktop are displayed but the menu and the launcher are still not there.

Also, when I try to run an application from CTRL + ALT + F1 such as `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` it says `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

I can only run applications with `export DISPLAY=:0`

**UPDATE 2:**

I've reinstalled my OS and everything went fine until it updated again. After the update, unity is once again unusable.

**UPDATE 3:**

I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and compiz was updated. Now the desktop icons are displayed but nothing more.
Also, after a reboot I got a System Error regarding Xorg. It somehow disappeared before I could see what generated the error. I tried to reboot again in order to see the error again but it didn't appear anymore.

Comment: Did you retry to remove your `~.Xauthority`-File? It is unlikely to solve your problem, but who knows...

Comment: @karel: I don't think it's a duplicate because none of the answers in there helped me.

Comment: @Kai: I tried it and it still doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could try to log in using the guest account

Comment: I was working fine too, clean install of 14.04... and did an update and reboot... and now I'm in "desktop blank" hell. Even adduser of a new account - same results. Dell Insperon with GT 650M.

Comment: I've reinstalled my OS and everything went fine until it updated again. After the update, unity is once again unusable.

Comment: After an update? So it appears you installed the nvidia drivers from source, correct? If so, you need to either install dkms before compiling the driver or just use the proprietary nvidia driver available through apt-get. Either one of these will prevent problems with upgrades.